# Prove the property of wave equation $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(f(x)+tg(x))dx$ given compactly supported initial condition.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(t,x)$ be the solution of the wave equation:
\begin{align*}
u_{tt}&=\Delta u \\
u(0,x)&=f(x) \\
u_t(0,x)&=g(x) \\
\end{align*}
where $t\in [0,\infty)$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ and $g$ are compactly supported.
Show that  $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(f(x)+tg(x))dx$

I have tried to use the Kirchhoff's formulas to verify directly but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure it's $\int_{\mathbb R^n} u_t(t,x)dx$ and not $\int_{\mathbb R^n} u(t,x)dx$ ?

Comment: I copied the question correctly but I managed to prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t(t,x)$ is constant in $t$ so it may be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was $\int_{\mathbb R^n} u(t,x)dx$, then according to the Newton-Leibniz theorem we'd have
$$ u(t,x) -u(0,x) = \int_{0}^t u_t(s,x)ds = \int_0^t u_t(0,x) +  \int_0^s u_{tt}(w,x)dwds   $$
where $u_t(0,x) = g(x)$ and $u(0,x) = f(x)$, hence
$$ u(t,x) = f(x) + tg(x) + \int_0^t\int_0^s u_{tt}(w,x)dwds. $$
Integrating w.r.t. $x$ would yield
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} u(t,x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n}(f(x)+tg(x))dx + \int_0^t\int_0^s \int_{\mathbb R^n} \Delta u(w,x)dxdwds. $$
If $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are compactly supported then $u(t,x)$ is also compactly supported, so there would exist compact sets $K_0\subset K\subset \mathbb R^n$ s.t. 
$u|_{K_0^c} =0$, therefore
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \Delta u(t,x)dx = \int_K \Delta u(t,x)dx = \oint_{\partial K} \nabla u \cdot d{\bf S} =0$$
where the last equality was due to the divergence theorem.