# Wave equation in N-Dimension

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I encounter a difficulty which is I cannot solve part (b) and (c).

[image]

Besides doing in 2D or 3D, I want to get a feeling in 1D first. Suppose we are in 1D, the solution of wave equation having specific boundary conditions is given by d'Alembert's principle:

\begin{equation}
u(t,x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(f(x+t) - f(x-t) \right) + \frac{1}{2} \int^{x+t}_{x-t} g(y)dy  
\end{equation}
For part (b), in order to show  $ \int_{\mathbb{R^{n}}} u_{t}(t,x) dx$ is constant in time, I differentiate this function with respect to time and we want to show the following is true(eg: in 1D):

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{t} dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{tt}dx= 0 
\end{equation}

since we have the solution of wave equation $u(t,x)$, we can differentiate twice with respect to time to get $u_{tt}$

\begin{equation}
u_{tt} = \frac{1}{2} \left( f''(x+t) - f"(x-t) \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( g'(x+t) + g'(x-t) \right)
\end{equation}

Therefore, we can plug in $u_{tt}$ into the integral: 
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( f''(x+t) - f''(x-t)  + g'(x+t) + g'(x-t) \right) dx 
\end{equation}

And this integral is my difficulty as I do not know how to make this integral to be 0. Could someone can help me to solve my question? Thank you.

Comment: There is typo in part (c). It should be $\int_{\mathbb R^n} u(t,x)dx$. Otherwise it would contradict (b), since the integral in (c) is not constant in time as (b) suggests.

Comment: Thank you Mick to point out the typo. I have amended this question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591229/prove-the-property-of-wave-equation-int-mathbbrnu-tt-x-int-mathbbr?noredirect=1#comment7383501_3591229

Comment: Thank you for you help, @Mick. I think the person who raised the similar question is one of my classmate XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) Integrating the equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then in $(0,t)$ and usingin the initial condition, we obtain $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_0^tu_{tt}(\tau,x)d\tau dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t(t,x)dx-\int g(x)dx=\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Delta u(\tau,x)dxd\tau.
$$
On the other hand, by using the fact that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$ the solution $u(t,\cdot)$ is compactly supported, by the Divergence's Theorem it is easy to check that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ it holds $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Delta u(t,x)dx=0.
$$
Therefore, plugging the last identity into the first one we conclude $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t(t,x)dx-\int g(x)dx=0 \quad \implies \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t(t,x)dx=\int g(x)dx,
$$
and hence it is constant in time. Part (c) has been recently solved here: [Prove the property of wave equation $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(f(x)+tg(x))dx$ given compactly supported initial condition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3591229/595711)

**Edit:** Just to be more clear, in order to show that $\int\Delta u=0$ you just need to pick a sufficiently large open bounded set $B_t\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that, at time $t$, the support of $u(t,\cdot)$ is strictly contained in $B_t$. Then, the Divergence's Theorem immediately gives you the conclusion just by noting that $\nabla u\cdot \vec{n}=0$ on $\partial B_t$.